# Starting a foreground service when an app is background restricted on Android Pie

Tags: android, foreground-service

With Android 9.0 (Pie), it's possible for the user to restrict your app from doing background work through settings. Our app has seen the following exception when we try to start a foreground service on Pie devices if the app is background restricted even when an app activity is fully in the foreground.

```
RemoteServiceException: Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground()
```

We do call startForeground() in the started Service, but the system log when attempting to start the service shows:

```
system_process W/ActivityManager: Service.startForeground() not allowed due to bg restriction
```

Seems odd to receive an exception when you're following [the documented steps](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services#Foreground) for foreground services, and the system is rejecting the app from starting the foreground service when your app is also in the foreground still. I have yet to find much documentation relating to this, but is this documented behavior? And is there at least a way for your app to know if it's been background restricted and thus not attempt to start the service in the foreground?

[image]

My Service code essentially looks like below. Our target api is 27.

```
class MyService : Service() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        // create notification
        startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification)
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        if (intent == null || intent.action == null || intent.action == ACTION_STOP) {
            quit()
        }
        doWork()
        return START_NOT_STICKY
    }

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

    override fun onTaskRemoved(rootIntent: Intent?) {
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent)
        quit()
    }

    private fun quit() {
        stopForeground(true)
        stopSelf()
    }

    companion object {

        fun start(context: Context) {
            val intent = Intent(context, MyService::class.java)
            intent.action = ACTION_START
            ContextCompat.startForegroundService(context, intent)
        }

        fun stop(context: Context) {
            val intent = Intent(context, MyService::class.java)
            intent.action = ACTION_STOP
            ContextCompat.startForegroundService(context, intent)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How is your service declared in your manifest?

Comment: @MichaelKrause It jus has the normal `name` and `export="false"`

Comment: Can you show the code that calls startForegroundService as well as the code that calls startForeground with the notification id and notification?  Also, what is your targetApi set to?

Comment: @MichaelKrause Yeah, sure. I updated the post. We target 27, but this only happens with devices running 28. Regardless, still having trouble finding documentation relating to the log message `Service.startForeground() not allowed due to bg restriction` and whether there's a new API to tell if your app is background restricted. There's `UsageStatsManager.getAppStandbyBucket`, but documentation doesn't mention user-restricted apps.

Comment: Ah - I see.  That is weird as you mentioned your app is visibly in the foreground.  Are you certain your activity is resumed?  For example, what would you see if you logged your various Activity lifecycle callbacks when this happens?  Are you really in a resumed state?

Comment: @MichaelKrause figured out the cause. See my answer if still interested. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Figured out that the crash will actually happen from the second call to *ContextCompat.startForegroundService()* in *MyService.stop()*, which I was using to send an Intent with a "stop" Action to stop the service rather than calling *context.stopService()*. At first I though I needed to manually call *stopForeground()* in the Service, but calling context.stopService() seems to stop the foreground service and remove the notification anyways and won't lead to the crash, so I've decided to refactor how I handle stopping the service.

UPDATE: I think an additional part of the problem was also trying to use Intents to start and stop the service, especially because in some cases my service was started and then stopped too quickly. A very helpful [thread with Ian Lake](https://plus.google.com/116630648530850689477/posts/L2rn4T6SAJ5) gives these recommendations about services:

> I'd strongly suggest against using startService as a way to pass messages to your service. Using an EventBus or LocalBroadcastReceiver is a lot better way of passing messages without conflating that with lifecycle actions. I'd also avoid having external components call stopService() directly - let the service itself manage its own lifecycle, reacting to events you send its way.

Comment: I've faced the same issue. I don't understand you clearly. Why manually calling stopForeground() in the Service causes crash on API 28? plz tell me what's your current solution?

Comment: Is there anything related to restricted app?

Comment: @HuyDuongTu I think the crash would come after my second call to ContextCompat.startForegroundService() that I was using to stop the service, but only if the app was background restricted because the startForeground already failed. Not entirely sure why the system chooses to crash. Overall, the bigger issue was that I was using Intents to control starting and stopping the service. Ian Lake highly recommends lettings the service control it's own lifecycle, so to best avoid issues starting and stopping. Checkout this convo: https://plus.google.com/116630648530850689477/posts/L2rn4T6SAJ5